# mysql запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Общая таблица `sol` имеет столбец с уникальным `ID` и др.
Дополнительная `user_db` имеет `user_id` и `cv_id`. столбец `cv_id` равняется столбцу из таблицы `sol.ID`

Как вывести все записи из таблицы `sol` где `user_db.cv_id` равняется `sol.ID` для пользователя например `user_db.user_id = 123`.

Comment: вам необходимо воспользоваться оператором `JOIN`. Ссылки [en](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)/[ru](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте JOIN, в вашем случаи будет так

```
SELECT
  sol.*
FROM sol
  INNER JOIN user_db
    ON user_db.cv_id = sol.id
WHERE user_db.user_id = 12
```